# Atm/Debit card Security

Tags: privacy

Is it possible for a person who has your **ATM/debit card number** and PIN, to withdraw your money? If so, how?

Comment: What password..? PIN number? Online password?

Comment: @Peanut Edited to specify PIN as online account hacking is pretty common knowledge. (Log into internet banking (card number is usually 'username') and use password to access accounts).

Comment: umm... if they have your card AND your PIN, then it is trivially obvious that they can withdraw your cash...??

Comment: @AviD The question is asking if they have your card number, not your card.

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of pieces of information in addition to the card number and the PIN, but this is pretty close to accurate.  Card cloning is a common crime and there are criminals who even do it right on the machine itself.  By copying the ATM card and recording the PIN, it is possible to access the account and withdraw money from it.  Fake faceplates can be installed on most ATMs to read the magnetic strip on the card and record the PIN number entered.  This is why it is always important to examine an ATM before you use it to ensure that it has not been tampered with.

Comment: I'm yet to see an ATM (that's being used) that can't be skimmed somehow. I've seen 'concepts' but that's about it...

Comment: It's a cat and mouse game

Comment: Note this is only a danger for places that use and accept mag stripe transactions, EMV (Chip and PIN) based cards using DDA/CDA aren't cloneable. Unfortunately most countries that use EMV have kept mag stripe around for legacy reasons, although the plan is to phase them out, and it's possible to get an EMV ATM to use the mag stripe if you break the EMV chip.

Comment: UK ATM's use "shuffle" card entry to help reduce the threat of surface skimmers.  The card stutters in and out as the card is entered into the machine.  Also, machines here tend to use the chip rather than the mag stripe.

Comment: How does shuffle card entry help reduce the threat of skimmers?

Comment: @Frank B: If the card is not fed or inserted in one smooth move, but rather stopped at random intervals or even moved back and forth, the magnetic strip reader in an attached skimming device will be less likely to capture the data on the card.

Comment: @FrankB - magnetic cards are read based on the timing of how long magnetic information is present.  Altering that time as it is read means that the skimmer has a hard time knowing how many 1s or 0s occur in order while the magnetism is oriented in a consistent direction. It can't distinguish 1,0,0,0,0,1 from 1, 0, pause, 1.  You'll actually hit the same problem if you scan half of a mag stripe at one speed and then alter your speed partway through.

Comment: That's a really smart way of beating the scammers. Of course the chips are better, but I'm impressed.

Comment: the main question is if someone have your ATM/Debit card number not card and security pin then he/she withdraw money from your account or not.if yes then how?

Comment: @Rishi - if you have the information that is encoded on the card, then it is possible.  It additionally includes the expiration date, verification code, sequence number and there might be one or two other things, so just the card number and pin won't allow a duplicate to be made, but it's a significant portion of the information needed.

Comment: yes i hv all other detail like exp date,verification code,sequence number etc